# How to collect the network traffic of a webView in Android?

Tags: java, android, webview, network-traffic

I'm building a SpeedTest app in android. One part of that app is a Browsing test, ie., Loading different web pages in a webView and calculating the time and performance rating. I have the time part figured out. But in order to calculate the PR, I need to know the data used while loading each website. I have the time part figured out. Any ideas on how to calculate the data used? I'm currently using getUidRxBytes() but that doesn't work since it gives me the entire network traffic since the boot-up.

This is the code

```
public class  BrowsingTestFragment extends Fragment {
View rootView;
WebView myWebView;
Button start;
boolean startTesting;
String[] mStrings;
private int i = 0;
long last_page_start;
long now;
long exactTime;
TextView time1, time2, time3, time4, time5,weight1,weight2,weight3,weight4,weight5;
Handler handler;
Runnable webUpdater = null;
BrowsingTestFragment context;
String[] testArray = new String[5];
int j=0; int foo;
String s;
double kb;
String dataReceived;


public BrowsingTestFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browsingtest, container, false);
    myWebView = new WebView(getContext());
    myWebView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mStrings = new String[]{
            "https://www.google.com",
            "https://www.facebook.com",
            "https://www.twitter.com",
            "https://www.wikipedia.org",
            "https://www.linkedin.com"
    };

    time1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    time2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    time3 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    time4 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    time5 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
    weight1=rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    start = rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    weight1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    weight2= rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    weight3= rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    weight4= rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    weight5= rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView16);

    startTesting = false;
    myWebView.clearCache(true);
    myWebView.clearHistory();
    myWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            time1.setText(R.string.defaultString);
            time2.setText(R.string.defaultString);
            time3.setText(R.string.defaultString);
            time4.setText(R.string.defaultString);
            time5.setText(R.string.defaultString);
            weight1.setText(R.string.defaultString);
            weight2.setText(R.string.defaultString);
            weight3.setText(R.string.defaultString);
            weight4.setText(R.string.defaultString);
            weight5.setText(R.string.defaultString);
            last_page_start = now = exactTime = 0;
            myWebView.clearCache(true);
            myWebView.clearHistory();
            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            myWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
            myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            if (!startTesting) {
                i = 0;
                startTesting = true;
                myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                startLoadURLs();
            } else {
                startTesting = false;
                myWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        boolean redirect = false;

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            dataReceived=null;
            dataReceived=String.valueOf(TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(android.os.Process.myUid()));
            foo= Integer.parseInt(dataReceived);
            kb= Math.round(((double) foo/8192)*.9);
            s=String.valueOf(kb);
            testArray[j]=s;
            j++;

            Log.i("onPageStartedurl", "onPageStarted last_page_start" + last_page_start);
            if (redirect == false)
                last_page_start = System.nanoTime();
            Log.i("onPageStartedurl", "onPageStarted last_page_start" + last_page_start);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            now = System.nanoTime();
            Log.i("onPageFinishedurl", "onPageFinished now" + now);

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            Log.i("onReceivedErrorurl", "onReceivedError");
            now = last_page_start;
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}

private void startLoadURLs() {

    MainActivity.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    myWebView.loadUrl(mStrings[i]);
    Log.i("mStringsurl", "mStrings" + mStrings[i]);
    handler = new Handler();
    webUpdater = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            exactTime = now - last_page_start;
            Log.i("exactTimeurl", "exactTime" + exactTime);
            double elapsedTimeInSecond = Math.round(((double) exactTime / 1000000000) * 100.0) / 100.0;
            Log.i("elapsedTimeInSecondurl", "elapsedTimeInSecond" + elapsedTimeInSecond);
            if (i == 0) {
                time1.setText("" + elapsedTimeInSecond + " s");
                weight1.setText(testArray[0]+"kiB");
            } else if (i == 1) {
                time2.setText("" + elapsedTimeInSecond + " s");
                weight2.setText(testArray[1]+"kiB");
            } else if (i == 2) {
                time3.setText("" + elapsedTimeInSecond + " s");
                weight3.setText(testArray[2]+"kiB");
            } else if (i == 3) {
                time4.setText("" + elapsedTimeInSecond + " s");
                weight4.setText(testArray[3]+"kiB");
            } else if (i == 4) {
                time5.setText("" + elapsedTimeInSecond + " s");
                weight5.setText(testArray[4]+"kiB");
            }
            ++i;
            if (i < mStrings.length) {
                myWebView.clearCache(true);
                myWebView.clearHistory();
                myWebView.clearFormData();
                myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
                myWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
                startLoadURLs();
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(webUpdater);
                startTesting = false;
                myWebView.clearCache(true);
                myWebView.clearHistory();
                myWebView.clearFormData();
                myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
                myWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
                myWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MainActivity.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(webUpdater, 5000); // 5 seconds

}

private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {


    public MyWebChromeClient(BrowsingTestFragment browsingTestFragment) {
        super();
        context = browsingTestFragment;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    try {
        if (startTesting) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(webUpdater);
            startTesting = false;
            myWebView.clearCache(true);
            myWebView.clearHistory();
            myWebView.clearFormData();
            myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            myWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
            myWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MainActivity.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Testting is terminatted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Call `getUidRxBytes()` before loading the page. Call `getUidRxBytes()` after loading the page. Subtract the two to get the number of bytes received while loading the page.

Comment: use them where to be exact in this code ?